# Actualizar el Stock de los productos de WordPress-WooCommerce desde otro sitio

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Estoy obteniendo los productos que están en otra tienda (Tienda Origen) a la cual tengo acceso solo a través de apis tales como url/listAllproduct o url/productStock?id=1 y los estoy cargando a mi tienda con la api de Woocommerce hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que el stock de los productos de la tienda origen son muy cambiantes lo que me obliga a actualizar el stock de todos mis productos cada cierto tiempo.

Quisiera saber como como puedo ejecutar mi script de actualización solo para el producto que se esta observando en la pagina Single_product o actualizar todos los productos que se están viendo en una pagina de la tienda antes de que la pagina se cargue para mostrar el stock actualizado.

He estado investigando los hook pero no logro hallar una solución y no se si los hooks realmente me puedan ayudar.

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: No se si exista un hook para eso, pero esto parece mas un trabajo para un custom endpoint, tendrás que crear un Endpoint personalizado que haga ese update y ejecutarlo en el single, debido a que no mencionas si estas solo mostrando datos o estas duplicando productos por medio de la API no sabría decirte que hacer exactamente pero por como lo mencionas un Custom Endpoint seria la solución, sin embargo necesitaras saber php y un poco del core de WordPress para hacerlo así, ya que si solo estas mostrando no debería ser problema pues siempre mostrara el ultimo valor.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta estimado, estoy duplicando los productos ya que traigo los productos y los creo en mi sitio

Comment: En ese caso puedes en el segundo sitio escuchar la acción de cuando se actualiza un producto con woocommerce_update_product, obtener el nuevo stock y enviar un request con php curl al primer sitio, actualizar el stock con el nuevo y listo, pero necesitaras saber el id del producto y como dije, posiblemente necesites un custom endpoint

Comment: @JefferzonBol me disculpo por no comentar que el primer sitio no esta en WordPress y solo tengo acceso a los productos a través de un api que me devuelve todos los productos

Comment: bueno, aun asi sigue siendo casi lo mismo, escuchas cuando se actualice el producto, obtienes el stock actual y lo envias a un endpoint del sitio que recibe los productos, accedes a la DB y actualizas el producto con el nuevo stock, debido a que no hay codigo y no sabemos como esta hecha tu app es lo maximo en lo que podemos ayudarte, pero almenos te puedes dar una idea en como resolverlo.

Comment: @JefferzonBol el problema esta en que no hay forma de escuchar cuando un producto se actualiza en la tienda origen para actualizarlo a mi tienda, lo único que puedo hacer es consultar la api que me dio la tienda origen para obtener los productos u obtener el stock de uno o varios productos

Comment: Ah entiendo, en ese caso no hay nada que puedas hacer mas que preguntar a ellos si existe una forma de saber si un producto se actualiza, ya que al ser un servicio externo no podemos ayudarte mas.

Comment: @JefferzonBol no hay una forma de ejecutar mi script al momento de pinchar en un producto de la tienda o antes de cargarse la pagina single_product

Comment: claro, puedes hacerlo usando el hook init pero de nuevo, no estas mostrando nada de codigo, asi que especular es lo unico que podemos hacer, por favor considera leer [ask] y como hacer un [example]